# yii gridview set checkbox without $model value

Tags: checkbox, datagridview, yii2, set, checked

I have the problem that I cant get the necessary values into the checkbox value field of my gridview. The checkboxfield can be checked or unchecked.
Therfore in the database there is a boolean field called member, for datagrid values with 0 is not checked and 1 is checked.

Usually the gridview has four columns. For testing purpose I print the column 'member' of the database table in an extra field in front of the checkbox column to see whether the values of the tablecolumn 'member' are right.

Because the view has two different dataProvdiders, $dataProvider and $dataProviderMembers, I cannot use the $model object. The $model object belongs to the content of $dataProvider. The dataviewgrid will be filled by the second dataprovider $dataProviderMembers.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProviderMembers,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id',
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'member',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
                return ['checked' => 'member'];
            }, 'header' => 'Mitglied'
            ],
            ]
    ]); ?>
```

Controller methode:

```
$searchModel = new PeriodeClassSubjectMembersSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

$modelPeriodeClassSubjectMembers = new PeriodeClassSubjectMembers();
        $dataProviderMembers = $modelPeriodeClassSubjectMembers->getPeriodeClassMembers($class_id, $periode_id, false);
        $dataProviderMembers->key = 'id'; //set this to make the id column as value columns in the gridview for javascript getselectedrows instead of the gridrow number
        return $this->render('viewmysubject', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'dataProviderMembers' => $dataProviderMembers
        ]);
```

Model methode for $dataProviderMembers:

```
$query = new Query();
        $query->select(..........);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);

return $dataProvider;
```

With this method, the checkbox field is not filled correkt.

Normal the checkbox field will be filled by the segment

```
return ['checked' => $model->member};
```

In this case there is no $model with values for member. $model belongs to the data of $dataProvider.

But I get the values for member from $dataProviderMembers.
As I can see in the column 'member', which is before the checkbox field of the datagrid, the values from the database are right filled into the grid. How can I fill the checkbox field without $model, instead with values of the 'member' column (member values of $dataProviderMembers) of the sql query in behind? Which means something like :

```
return ['checked' => 'member'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gridview the dataProvider is equal to $dataProviderMembers 
then the $model param in anonymous function  for checkboxOptions is related the models that should contain the member values 
So  You could get to value using $model->member

```
        [   'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 
            'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
            return ['value' => $model->member];
           }, 
        ],
```

or if the dataProvider is an array

```
      [   'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 
            'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
            return ['value' => $model['member']];
           }, 
        ],
```

Comment: When Iam using $model->member on this position, which is working in normal cases, I get an yii\base\ErrorException with 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

Comment: Are you sure  your  dataProvider is $dataProviderMembers  and contain really the attribute member ..  try add the controller action code please .

Comment: Yes, the dataggridview will be filled by the $dataProviderMembers correctly. I can see also the proper member values in the additional column 'member', which I had created for testing purposes (the column before the checkbox column), I have also added now the major part of the controller function.

Comment: The column member is an additional column?   . show the related  model and how you populate this field please.. (ps   .. how in you action you a sending/render a $dataProvider but this dataProvider is not set?)

Comment: The additional column member in the datagrid view in front of the checkbox column is just temporer for testing, to see wheter the member values are working and to see if they are correct from the model. The values from member are correct, but I need them for setting the checkbox fields and this is not working. $dataProvider is used to get other data into the view and is set in the controller (controller information in question is updated).

Comment: answer  updated with a suggestion  (could be that the dataProviderMember is not a collection of models but an array )   ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153945/discussion-between-perino-and-scaisedge).

Comment: It seems that the needed returning value is packed into an Array within an object. With return ['value' => $model['member']] I can use the member values for setting the checkboxes in this case! Thx to scaisEdge!